# Mixed partial derivative not square-integrable

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

recently I have been wondering one thing: is it easy to come up with a (2-d) function that has square-integrable first derivatives but does not have a square-integrable mixed derivative?

That is, are there any simple and natural functions $f(x,y)$ that satisfy $\int_0^1\int_{0}^1 f_x(x,y)^2dxdy < \infty$, $\int_0^1\int_{0}^1 f_y(x,y)^2dxdy < \infty$ where $f_x(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y), f_y = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)$. But $f_{xy}(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}f(x,y)$ satisfies $\int_0^1\int_0^1 f_{xy}(x,y)^2dxdy = \infty$.

The most promising one that I can come up with is the function $f(x,y) = \max(x+y-1, 0)$ that will generate "a Dirac function on a line" after taking the mixed derivative, which I suspect is square-integrable. But I receive little training on 2-d Dirac functions so I am not 100% sure.

Much appreciation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x+y}$ does the job.

Indeed $f_x(x,y)=f_y(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+y}}$ is square integrable on $[0,1]^2$ since (Tonelli)
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{x+y}dxdy=\int_0^1 \ln(1+y)-\ln(y) dy$$ which is finite, whereas $f_{xy}(x,y)=-\frac{1}{4(x+y)^{3/2}}$ is not since
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x+y)^3}dxdy=\frac13\int_0^1 \frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy$$ which is infinite.

Comment: Terrific answer using the square root functions!